# Margins in 2D image plot after adding scatterplot point in Matplotlib

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, matplotlib, astronomy

I am trying to label points on the image, but whenever I do an extra marker on the plots by coordinate values and the margins becomes unnecessarily large. What is the issue here, and is there a way to fix this?

The image is fine. I even plotted it below and everything seems okay when I don't add the plotted point.

```
imp = plt.imshow(processed[::-1],cmap='gray_r',vmin=1000,vmax=2000)
plt.colorbar()
plt.figure()
imp = plt.imshow(processed[::-1],cmap='gray_r',vmin=1000,vmax=2000)
plt.plot(600,400,'*',color='r')
plt.colorbar()
```

[Large Margin around image generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAerd.png)
[image]

Comment: What about `plt.axis('tight')`?

Comment: are the images you posted in the wrong order?

Comment: Ok the ``plt.axis('tight')`` made it work. Thanks!